# Finding the limit this recursive function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Define

$x_0 = 1$ and $x_n = \dfrac{1}{10}x_{n-1} + x_{n-1} \sin(x_{n-1})$

Note that $x_n$ can also be written as $x_n = x_{n-1} \left(\dfrac{1}{10} + \sin(x_{n-1})\right)$

How would you find the limit of this value? That is,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$$

I've already proved that $x_n < x_{n-1}$ and that $x_n \leq 1$, so I know that the limit exists, and I'm guessing that the limit is $0$, but how do I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before rigourously proving anything we want to find the limit, $L$. So, we note that a convergent sequence is Cauchy in R and so we use the fact that $|x_{n}-x_{n-1}|<\varepsilon$. So, we have a fixed point at $L = \frac{1}{10}\cdot L + L\cdot \text{sin}(L)$. That is $\text{sin}(L) = \frac{9}{10}$ or $L=\text{sin}^{-1}(\frac{9}{10})$ In fact, we want to be careful. As you pointed out $x_{n}\leq x_{n-1}$ and since $x_{0} = 1$, we should get $L = 0$. If $x_{0}\geq \text{sin}^{-1}(\frac{9}{10})$, only then could $L =\text{sin}^{-1}(\frac{9}{10})$ if it even converges to this fixed point at all. Note the comment by Vargas that the point is, in fact, unstable.

Comment: Is this a typo? $ \sin L = \frac{9}{10} \Rightarrow L=\arcsin \frac{9}{10}$

Comment: This is not correct.  The equilibrium at $\sin^{-1}(9/10)$ is unstable; as long as $x_0 \neq \sin^{-1}(9/10)$ it will never be true that $x_n \to \sin^{-1}(9/10)$.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the typo correction. I usually use $x_{0}$ as the fixed point, but it was already used in the question. I missed it when re-editing...

Comment: Antonio Vargas, good point. I should have checked more carefully - I didn't. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Taking limits in the recurrence relation we see that the limit must satisfy the equation
$$
x=\frac{1}{10}\,x+x\sin x.
$$
There are two solutions: $x=0$, $x=\arcsin(9/10)=1.119\dots$. Since the limit is smaller than $1$, it must be $0$.

Comment: To take the limit of the recurrence relation, you need to take the limits on both sides right ? How does you take the limit of $sin(x_{n-1})$ ?

Comment: First of all, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}$. Next, since $\sin$ is a continuous function, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(x_{n-1})=\sin(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n-1})$.

Comment: Thanks, I've never come accross any theorem saying that if $f$ is a continous function then you can move the limit into the function, but that makes the limit equality clear for me.